# Strange Character on IMG Link?

Tags: php, html, dhtml

> **Exact Duplicate:** [strange characters on IMG Link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925331/strange-characters-on-img-link-closed)

Hello all

im using an open source Auto Dealer database made in PHP CMS style. usally when you copy and paste html code on the comments text box on any cms you can edit the page layout with images and fonts. I did this and it did change the layout as i wanted but one problem is that the images that i want to show dont show up they show up as broken images and when i see the source: http://www.webpage.com/dealer/%5C%22http%3A//www.webpage.com/images/gallery/clone/clone-000.jpg%5C%22

the way input it on the code is: http://www.webpage.com/images/gallery/clone/clone-000.jpg

is there way i can by pass these symbols and have the image show up or is there something blocking any image from showing. I'm running my own server btw.

PS: this is strictly programmer related if this has to do with any code edit then then its basic programmer related for those who don't bind by that please ignore the question let someone that could solve it solve it thanks.

Comment: didn't you just post this same question about an hour ago?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925331/strange-characters-on-img-link-closed

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... two thoughts:

1) The CMS is trying to be "smart" about links, and is adding base URL of the site to the url of the image. You should check the configuration settings of the CMS and see what's there.

2) The editor in the CMS is doing the same thing, and you will have to tweak the settings of *that*!

The %5C%22 is what you get when the CMS or the editor performs a web-safe encoding of a string (although I have no idea why it's placing that at the end).

I hope this gives you a couple pointers on where to look! Perhaps you can post back what CMS and editor module you are using?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks as though your cms is looking for a relative url. from "~/root/dealer"

you should move your "images/gallery..." folder to that spot
then referance your images src="images/gallery/clone/clone-000.jpg"

Answer (score -1):

All I had to do is add this to my code: `<img src=http:www.mysite.com/image.jpeg>`